# psycopg2 returns numbers as string

Tags: python, psycopg2

Every time I try to return numbers with psycopg2(saved as numeric), they end up being of string data type.

How can I return them as int, float, or double?

Comment: Can you give an example of code that is returning the wrong result?

Comment: Can't use you just use `int`?

Comment: What version of Python are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [FAQ](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/faq.html#faq-float) describes a method for doing this. You basically register a type handler. Search for `Numeric` on that page. According to the FAQ, you do this:

```
DEC2FLOAT = psycopg2.extensions.new_type(
    psycopg2.extensions.DECIMAL.values,
    'DEC2FLOAT',
    lambda value, curs: float(value) if value is not None else None)
psycopg2.extensions.register_type(DEC2FLOAT)
```